# Why the natural join's result rows count smaller than join's?

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, inner-join

The database data is from http://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/join-exercises/

```
        sqlite> select * from employees;
        EMPLOYEE_ID  FIRST_NAME     LAST_NAME      EMAIL       PHONE_NUMBER          HIRE_DATE     JOB_ID        SALARY      COMMISSION_PCT  MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID
        -----------  -------------  -------------  ----------  --------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  --------------  ----------  -------------
        100           Steven         King           SKING       515.123.4567          1987-06-17    AD_PRES      24000       0.0             0           90
        101           Neena          Kochhar        NKOCHHAR    515.123.4568          1987-06-18    AD_VP        17000       0.0             100         90
        102           Lex            De Haan        LDEHAAN     515.123.4569          1987-06-19    AD_VP        17000       0.0             100         90
...
        202           Pat            Fay            PFAY        603.123.6666          1987-09-27    MK_REP       6000        0.0             201         20
        203           Susan          Mavris         SMAVRIS     515.123.7777          1987-09-28    HR_REP       6500        0.0             101         40
        204           Hermann        Baer           HBAER       515.123.8888          1987-09-29    PR_REP       10000       0.0             101         70
        205           Shelley        Higgins        SHIGGINS    515.123.8080          1987-09-30    AC_MGR       12000       0.0             101         110
        206           William        Gietz          WGIETZ      515.123.8181          1987-10-01    AC_ACCOUNT   8300        0.0             205         110
    sqlite> select * from departments;
    DEPARTMENT_ID  DEPARTMENT_NAME         MANAGER_ID  LOCATION_ID
    -------------  ----------------------  ----------  -----------
    10              Administration         200         1700
    20              Marketing              201         1800
    30              Purchasing             114         1700
    40              Human Resources        203         2400
    50              Shipping               121         1500
    60              IT                     103         1400
    70              Public Relations       204         2700
    80              Sales                  145         2500
    90              Executive              100         1700
    100             Finance                108         1700
    110             Accounting             205         1700
    120             Treasury               0           1700
    130             Corporate Tax          0           1700
    140             Control And Credit     0           1700
    150             Shareholder Services   0           1700
    160             Benefits               0           1700
    170             Manufacturing          0           1700
    180             Construction           0           1700
    190             Contracting            0           1700
    200             Operations             0           1700
    210             IT Support             0           1700
    220             NOC                    0           1700
    230             IT Helpdesk            0           1700
    240             Government Sales       0           1700
    250             Retail Sales           0           1700
    260             Recruiting             0           1700
    270             Payroll                0           1700
```

The natural join result:

```
sqlite> select * from employees e natural join departments d;
EMPLOYEE_ID  FIRST_NAME     LAST_NAME      EMAIL       PHONE_NUMBER          HIRE_DATE     JOB_ID        SALARY      COMMISSION_PCT  MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID  DEPARTMENT_NAME         LOCATION_ID
-----------  -------------  -------------  ----------  --------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  --------------  ----------  -------------  ----------------------  -----------
101           Neena          Kochhar        NKOCHHAR    515.123.4568          1987-06-18    AD_VP        17000       0.0             100         90              Executive              1700
102           Lex            De Haan        LDEHAAN     515.123.4569          1987-06-19    AD_VP        17000       0.0             100         90              Executive              1700
104           Bruce          Ernst          BERNST      590.423.4568          1987-06-21    IT_PROG      6000        0.0             103         60              IT                     1400
105           David          Austin         DAUSTIN     590.423.4569          1987-06-22    IT_PROG      4800        0.0             103         60              IT                     1400
106           Valli          Pataballa      VPATABAL    590.423.4560          1987-06-23    IT_PROG      4800        0.0             103         60              IT                     1400
107           Diana          Lorentz        DLORENTZ    590.423.5567          1987-06-24    IT_PROG      4200        0.0             103         60              IT                     1400
109           Daniel         Faviet         DFAVIET     515.124.4169          1987-06-26    FI_ACCOUNT   9000        0.0             108         100             Finance                1700
110           John           Chen           JCHEN       515.124.4269          1987-06-27    FI_ACCOUNT   8200        0.0             108         100             Finance                1700
111           Ismael         Sciarra        ISCIARRA    515.124.4369          1987-06-28    FI_ACCOUNT   7700        0.0             108         100             Finance                1700
112           Jose Manuel    Urman          JMURMAN     515.124.4469          1987-06-29    FI_ACCOUNT   7800        0.0             108         100             Finance                1700
113           Luis           Popp           LPOPP       515.124.4567          1987-06-30    FI_ACCOUNT   6900        0.0             108         100             Finance                1700
115           Alexander      Khoo           AKHOO       515.127.4562          1987-07-02    PU_CLERK     3100        0.0             114         30              Purchasing             1700
116           Shelli         Baida          SBAIDA      515.127.4563          1987-07-03    PU_CLERK     2900        0.0             114         30              Purchasing             1700
117           Sigal          Tobias         STOBIAS     515.127.4564          1987-07-04    PU_CLERK     2800        0.0             114         30              Purchasing             1700
118           Guy            Himuro         GHIMURO     515.127.4565          1987-07-05    PU_CLERK     2600        0.0             114         30              Purchasing             1700
119           Karen          Colmenares     KCOLMENA    515.127.4566          1987-07-06    PU_CLERK     2500        0.0             114         30              Purchasing             1700
129           Laura          Bissot         LBISSOT     650.124.5234          1987-07-16    ST_CLERK     3300        0.0             121         50              Shipping               1500
130           Mozhe          Atkinson       MATKINSO    650.124.6234          1987-07-17    ST_CLERK     2800        0.0             121         50              Shipping               1500
131           James          Marlow         JAMRLOW     650.124.7234          1987-07-18    ST_CLERK     2500        0.0             121         50              Shipping               1500
132           TJ             Olson          TJOLSON     650.124.8234          1987-07-19    ST_CLERK     2100        0.0             121         50              Shipping               1500
150           Peter          Tucker         PTUCKER     011.44.1344.129268    1987-08-06    SA_REP       10000       0.3             145         80              Sales                  2500
151           David          Bernstein      DBERNSTE    011.44.1344.345268    1987-08-07    SA_REP       9500        0.25            145         80              Sales                  2500
152           Peter          Hall           PHALL       011.44.1344.478968    1987-08-08    SA_REP       9000        0.25            145         80              Sales                  2500
153           Christopher    Olsen          COLSEN      011.44.1344.498718    1987-08-09    SA_REP       8000        0.2             145         80              Sales                  2500
154           Nanette        Cambrault      NCAMBRAU    011.44.1344.987668    1987-08-10    SA_REP       7500        0.2             145         80              Sales                  2500
155           Oliver         Tuvault        OTUVAULT    011.44.1344.486508    1987-08-11    SA_REP       7000        0.15            145         80              Sales                  2500
184           Nandita        Sarchand       NSARCHAN    650.509.1876          1987-09-09    SH_CLERK     4200        0.0             121         50              Shipping               1500
185           Alexis         Bull           ABULL       650.509.2876          1987-09-10    SH_CLERK     4100        0.0             121         50              Shipping               1500
186           Julia          Dellinger      JDELLING    650.509.3876          1987-09-11    SH_CLERK     3400        0.0             121         50              Shipping               1500
187           Anthony        Cabrio         ACABRIO     650.509.4876          1987-09-12    SH_CLERK     3000        0.0             121         50              Shipping               1500
202           Pat            Fay            PFAY        603.123.6666          1987-09-27    MK_REP       6000        0.0             201         20              Marketing              1800
206           William        Gietz          WGIETZ      515.123.8181          1987-10-01    AC_ACCOUNT   8300        0.0             205         110             Accounting             1700
sqlite> select count(*) from employees e natural join departments d;
count(*)
----------
32
```

The join result:

```
    sqlite> select * from employees e join departments d using 

    (department_id);
    EMPLOYEE_ID  FIRST_NAME     LAST_NAME      EMAIL       PHONE_NUMBER          HIRE_DATE     JOB_ID        SALARY      COMMISSION_PCT  MANAGER_ID  DEPARTMENT_ID  DEPARTMENT_NAME         MANAGER_ID  LOCATION_ID
    -----------  -------------  -------------  ----------  --------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  --------------  ----------  -------------  ----------------------  ----------  -----------
    100           Steven         King           SKING       515.123.4567          1987-06-17    AD_PRES      24000       0.0             0           90              Executive              100         1700
    101           Neena          Kochhar        NKOCHHAR    515.123.4568          1987-06-18    AD_VP        17000       0.0             100         90              Executive              100         1700
    102           Lex            De Haan        LDEHAAN     515.123.4569          1987-06-19    AD_VP        17000       0.0             100         90              Executive              100         1700
    103           Alexander      Hunold         AHUNOLD     590.423.4567          1987-06-20    IT_PROG      9000        0.0             102         60              IT                     103         1400
    104           Bruce          Ernst          BERNST      590.423.4568          1987-06-21    IT_PROG      6000        0.0             103         60              IT                     103         1400
    105           David          Austin         DAUSTIN     590.423.4569          1987-06-22    IT_PROG      4800        0.0             103         60              IT                     103         1400
    106           Valli          Pataballa      VPATABAL    590.423.4560          1987-06-23    IT_PROG      4800        0.0             103         60              IT                     103         1400
    107           Diana          Lorentz        DLORENTZ    590.423.5567          1987-06-24    IT_PROG      4200        0.0             103         60              IT                     103         1400
    108           Nancy          Greenberg      NGREENBE    515.124.4569          1987-06-25    FI_MGR       12000       0.0             101         100             Finance                108         1700
    109           Daniel         Faviet         DFAVIET     515.124.4169          1987-06-26    FI_ACCOUNT   9000        0.0             108         100             Finance                108         1700
    110           John           Chen           JCHEN       515.124.4269          1987-06-27    FI_ACCOUNT   8200        0.0             108         100             Finance                108         1700
    111           Ismael         Sciarra        ISCIARRA    515.124.4369          1987-06-28    FI_ACCOUNT   7700        0.0             108         100             Finance                108         1700
    112           Jose Manuel    Urman          JMURMAN     515.124.4469          1987-06-29    FI_ACCOUNT   7800        0.0             108         100             Finance                108         1700
...

155           Oliver         Tuvault        OTUVAULT    011.44.1344.486508    1987-08-11    SA_REP       7000        0.15            145         80              Sales                  145         2500
156           Janette        King           JKING       011.44.1345.429268    1987-08-12    SA_REP       10000       0.35            146         80              Sales                  145         2500
157           Patrick        Sully          PSULLY      011.44.1345.929268    1987-08-13    SA_REP       9500        0.35            146         80              Sales                  145         2500
158           Allan          McEwen         AMCEWEN     011.44.1345.829268    1987-08-14    SA_REP       9000        0.35            146         80              Sales                  145         2500
159           Lindsey        Smith          LSMITH      011.44.1345.729268    1987-08-15    SA_REP       8000        0.3             146         80              Sales                  145         2500
160           Louise         Doran          LDORAN      011.44.1345.629268    1987-08-16    SA_REP       7500        0.3             146         80              Sales                  145         2500
161           Sarath         Sewall         SSEWALL     011.44.1345.529268    1987-08-17    SA_REP       7000        0.25            146         80              Sales                  145         2500
162           Clara          Vishney        CVISHNEY    011.44.1346.129268    1987-08-18    SA_REP       10500       0.25            147         80              Sales                  145         2500
163           Danielle       Greene         DGREENE     011.44.1346.229268    1987-08-19    SA_REP       9500        0.15            147         80              Sales                  145         2500
164           Mattea         Marvins        MMARVINS    011.44.1346.329268    1987-08-20    SA_REP       7200        0.1             147         80              Sales                  145         2500
165           David          Lee            DLEE        011.44.1346.529268    1987-08-21    SA_REP       6800        0.1             147         80              Sales                  145         2500
166           Sundar         Ande           SANDE       011.44.1346.629268    1987-08-22    SA_REP       6400        0.1             147         80              Sales                  145         2500
167           Amit           Banda          ABANDA      011.44.1346.729268    1987-08-23    SA_REP       6200        0.1             147         80              Sales                  145         2500
168           Lisa           Ozer           LOZER       011.44.1343.929268    1987-08-24    SA_REP       11500       0.25            148         80              Sales                  145         2500
169           Harrison       Bloom          HBLOOM      011.44.1343.829268    1987-08-25    SA_REP       10000       0.2             148         80              Sales                  145         2500
170           Tayler         Fox            TFOX        011.44.1343.729268    1987-08-26    SA_REP       9600        0.2             148         80              Sales                  145         2500
171           William        Smith          WSMITH      011.44.1343.629268    1987-08-27    SA_REP       7400        0.15            148         80              Sales                  145         2500
172           Elizabeth      Bates          EBATES      011.44.1343.529268    1987-08-28    SA_REP       7300        0.15            148         80              Sales                  145         2500
173           Sundita        Kumar          SKUMAR      011.44.1343.329268    1987-08-29    SA_REP       6100        0.1             148         80              Sales                  145         2500
174           Ellen          Abel           EABEL       011.44.1644.429267    1987-08-30    SA_REP       11000       0.3             149         80              Sales                  145         2500
175           Alyssa         Hutton         AHUTTON     011.44.1644.429266    1987-08-31    SA_REP       8800        0.25            149         80              Sales                  145         2500
176           Jonathon       Taylor         JTAYLOR     011.44.1644.429265    1987-09-01    SA_REP       8600        0.2             149         80              Sales                  145         2500
177           Jack           Livingston     JLIVINGS    011.44.1644.429264    1987-09-02    SA_REP       8400        0.2             149         80              Sales                  145         2500
179           Charles        Johnson        CJOHNSON    011.44.1644.429262    1987-09-04    SA_REP       6200        0.1             149         80              Sales                  145         2500
180           Winston        Taylor         WTAYLOR     650.507.9876          1987-09-05    SH_CLERK     3200        0.0             120         50              Shipping               121         1500
181           Jean           Fleaur         JFLEAUR     650.507.9877          1987-09-06    SH_CLERK     3100        0.0             120         50              Shipping               121         1500
182           Martha         Sullivan       MSULLIVA    650.507.9878          1987-09-07    SH_CLERK     2500        0.0             120         50              Shipping               121         1500
183           Girard         Geoni          GGEONI      650.507.9879          1987-09-08    SH_CLERK     2800        0.0             120         50              Shipping               121         1500
184           Nandita        Sarchand       NSARCHAN    650.509.1876          1987-09-09    SH_CLERK     4200        0.0             121         50              Shipping               121         1500
185           Alexis         Bull           ABULL       650.509.2876          1987-09-10    SH_CLERK     4100        0.0             121         50              Shipping               121         1500
186           Julia          Dellinger      JDELLING    650.509.3876          1987-09-11    SH_CLERK     3400        0.0             121         50              Shipping               121         1500
187           Anthony        Cabrio         ACABRIO     650.509.4876          1987-09-12    SH_CLERK     3000        0.0             121         50              Shipping               121         1500
188           Kelly          Chung          KCHUNG      650.505.1876          1987-09-13    SH_CLERK     3800        0.0             122         50              Shipping               121         1500
189           Jennifer       Dilly          JDILLY      650.505.2876          1987-09-14    SH_CLERK     3600        0.0             122         50              Shipping               121         1500
190           Timothy        Gates          TGATES      650.505.3876          1987-09-15    SH_CLERK     2900        0.0             122         50              Shipping               121         1500
191           Randall        Perkins        RPERKINS    650.505.4876          1987-09-16    SH_CLERK     2500        0.0             122         50              Shipping               121         1500
192           Sarah          Bell           SBELL       650.501.1876          1987-09-17    SH_CLERK     4000        0.0             123         50              Shipping               121         1500
193           Britney        Everett        BEVERETT    650.501.2876          1987-09-18    SH_CLERK     3900        0.0             123         50              Shipping               121         1500
194           Samuel         McCain         SMCCAIN     650.501.3876          1987-09-19    SH_CLERK     3200        0.0             123         50              Shipping               121         1500
195           Vance          Jones          VJONES      650.501.4876          1987-09-20    SH_CLERK     2800        0.0             123         50              Shipping               121         1500
196           Alana          Walsh          AWALSH      650.507.9811          1987-09-21    SH_CLERK     3100        0.0             124         50              Shipping               121         1500
197           Kevin          Feeney         KFEENEY     650.507.9822          1987-09-22    SH_CLERK     3000        0.0             124         50              Shipping               121         1500
198           Donald         OConnell       DOCONNEL    650.507.9833          1987-09-23    SH_CLERK     2600        0.0             124         50              Shipping               121         1500
199           Douglas        Grant          DGRANT      650.507.9844          1987-09-24    SH_CLERK     2600        0.0             124         50              Shipping               121         1500
200           Jennifer       Whalen         JWHALEN     515.123.4444          1987-09-25    AD_ASST      4400        0.0             101         10              Administration         200         1700
201           Michael        Hartstein      MHARTSTE    515.123.5555          1987-09-26    MK_MAN       13000       0.0             100         20              Marketing              201         1800
202           Pat            Fay            PFAY        603.123.6666          1987-09-27    MK_REP       6000        0.0             201         20              Marketing              201         1800
203           Susan          Mavris         SMAVRIS     515.123.7777          1987-09-28    HR_REP       6500        0.0             101         40              Human Resources        203         2400
204           Hermann        Baer           HBAER       515.123.8888          1987-09-29    PR_REP       10000       0.0             101         70              Public Relations       204         2700
205           Shelley        Higgins        SHIGGINS    515.123.8080          1987-09-30    AC_MGR       12000       0.0             101         110             Accounting             205         1700
206           William        Gietz          WGIETZ      515.123.8181          1987-10-01    AC_ACCOUNT   8300        0.0             205         110             Accounting             205         1700

sqlite> select count(*) from employees e join departments d using (department_id);
count(*)
----------
106
```

The natural join result rows count should be same as join, but not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different between a natural join and a 'normal' join is that the former use *all* columns that happen to have the same name in both tables.

In this case, both `DEPARTMENT_ID` and `MANAGER_ID` match, so the natural join is actually the same as this query:

```
select * from employees e join departments d using (department_id, manager_id);
```

This is why you should never, ever use a natural join.